# using sdl in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, sdl

i've successfully cross compiled the sdl library for the android platform now i want to display my sdl forms like SDL_Surface and the SDL_Rect in the android screen .
How is that possible?

here is my first try

```
  SDLRenderer::SDLRenderer    () :
         bmp            (NULL),
         screen         (NULL),
         imgConvertCtx  (NULL),
         isInit         (false),
         quitKeyPressed (false)
  {
  }
  SDLRenderer::~SDLRenderer   ()
  {
  }

  bool    SDLRenderer::init                   (int width, int height)
  {       LOGI("sdlrenderer init");
this->screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 0, 0);

  if(!screen){
    LOGI("!screen");
    return false;
  }

this->bmp = SDL_CreateYUVOverlay(width, height, SDL_YV12_OVERLAY, this->screen);

LOGI("SDL_CreateYUVOverlay passed");

return true;
}
bool    SDLRenderer::processEvents          ()
{
 SDL_Event sdlEvent;
 while(SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent))
 {
     switch(sdlEvent.type)
     {
         case SDL_KEYDOWN:
             if(sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                 this->quitKeyPressed = true;
             break;
         case SDL_QUIT: this->quitKeyPressed = true; break;
     } 
 }

 return true;
}
bool    SDLRenderer::isQuitKeyPressed       ()
{
return this->quitKeyPressed;
}
void    SDLRenderer::onVideoDataAvailable   (const uint8_t **data,         videoFrameProperties* props)
{LOGI("sdlrenderer data availabe");
   if(!this->isInit){
    this->isInit = this->init(props->width, props->height);
    LOGI("sdlrenderer data availabe calling render init"); 
   }
   LOGI("before     SDL_LockYUVOverlay(bmp);"); 

SDL_LockYUVOverlay(bmp);
LOGI("after     SDL_LockYUVOverlay(bmp);"); 

AVPicture pict;
LOGI("after    AVPicture pict;"); 

pict.data[0] = bmp->pixels[0];
pict.data[1] = bmp->pixels[2];
pict.data[2] = bmp->pixels[1];

pict.linesize[0] = bmp->pitches[0];
pict.linesize[1] = bmp->pitches[2];
pict.linesize[2] = bmp->pitches[1];
  LOGI("after     creating avpicture"); 

// Convert the image into YUV format that SDL uses
if(imgConvertCtx == NULL)
{
    int w = props->width;
    int h = props->height;

    imgConvertCtx = sws_getContext(props->width, props->height, (PixelFormat)props-     >pxlFmt, w, h, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if(imgConvertCtx == NULL)
    { LOGI("imgConvertCtx == NULL"); 

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initialize the conversion context!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

sws_scale(imgConvertCtx, data, props->linesize, 0, props->height, pict.data,   pict.linesize);
 LOGI("calling SDL_UnlockYUVOverlay(bmp);"); 

SDL_UnlockYUVOverlay(bmp);

rect.x = 0;
rect.y = 0;
rect.w = props->width;
rect.h = props->height;
LOGI("sdlrenderer displaying");
SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay(bmp, &rect);
}
```

there is my main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDLRenderer     *renderer = new SDLRenderer();
    DASHReceiver    *receiver = new DASHReceiver(30); 

    receiver->Init("http://www----custom url here");

    LibavDecoder *decoder = new LibavDecoder(receiver);

    decoder->attachVideoObserver(renderer);
    decoder->setFrameRate(24);
    decoder->init();

    bool eos = false;

    while(!renderer->isQuitKeyPressed() && !eos)
  {
      eos = !decoder->decode();
      renderer->processEvents();
   }

   decoder->stop();

return 0;
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try SDL_BlitSurface()?

Comment: What did you use then?

Comment: i've just aded what am using

Comment: Can you post your main loop?

Comment: i've just added my main loop

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an [`SDL_Flip`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Flip) or an [`SDL_UpdateRect`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_UpdateRect) to be called on your main SDL_surface, which will update it on the screen.

Comment: I've added SDL_UpdateRect in my main but nothing new happened
i think my problem is in how to call the sdl main from the java side and how to make the android screen show the sdl forms

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are trying to port the bitmovin opensource dash player.
I have already done that and once SDL was ported to android, all other parts of the sofware were working.
I've got exactly the same code as you and this part is working well
be sure to define the surface in the java part
Try google with SDLActivity and use the java code provided from here
Then take a carefull look here http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/sdl-libsdl.org/2011-July/081481.html to make some little modification to the java code

```
    // The Unimplemented OpenGL ES API notices *always* indicate you have
    // the incorrect context version, which has to be fixed in SDLActivity.java .
    int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
    int contextAttrs[] = new int[]{
                      EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, majorVersion,
                      EGL10.EGL_NONE
                       };
     EGLContext ctx = egl.eglCreateContext(dpy, config,EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttrs);
     if (ctx == EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
          Log.e("SDL", "Couldn't create context");
          return false;
     }

    /*
    EGLContext ctx = egl.eglCreateContext(dpy, config, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, null);
    if (ctx == EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
        Log.e("SDL", "Couldn't create context");
        return false;
    }
    */
```